# Finding infimum and proving continuity of a function

Tags: continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f : [a,b] \to\mathbb R$ and for every $x \in [a,b]$ there exists $y \in [a,b]$ such that $|f(y)| < \frac12|f(x)|$.

Find $\inf\{|f (x)| : x \in [a, b]\}$, and show that $f$ is not continuous on $[a, b]$.

I am fairly new to this type of calculus so I am not being able to start an approach regarding this, I think infimum will be a function out of the range of $f$ as according to the definition there will always be another term less than half of it.

Comment: that's right, and do you know any facts about whether the range of a continuous function on a compact interval must contain its infimum?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes I do and that is what I am trying to prove but I am having difficulty in proving/stating that the infimum will be out of the range mathematically, could you provide some insight please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part One.

Let $I=\{|f(x)|: x\in [a,b]\}.$ Let $D=\inf I.$

Then $D=0.$ Proof by contradiction: Suppose $D>0.$ By def'n of $D$ we have $$(i).\quad I\subset [D,\infty).$$ Now if $E>D$ then $$(ii).\quad I\cap [D,E]\ne \emptyset.$$ Otherwise, by $(i)$ we would have $I\subset [E,\infty),$ implying $ D=\inf I\ge \inf \,E>D.$

So in $(ii)$ take $E=3D/2.$  Then there exists $x\in [a,b]$ with $|f(x)|\in [D,E]=[D,3D/2].$ But then there exists $y\in [a,b]$ with $|f(y)|<|f(x)|/2\le 3D/4<D,$ contrary to $(i).$ This is the desired contradiction that follows from assuming $D>0$.

Part two.

$0=D=\inf I\not \in I.$ Otherwise for some $x\in [a,b]$ we would have $|f(x)|=0$ but then there would exist $y\in [a,b]$ with $|f(y)|<|f(x)|/2=0.$

Comment: If $J$ is any non-empty subset of $[0,\infty)$ such that $\forall j\in J\,\,\exists j'\in J\,(j'\le j/2)$ then $\inf J=0.$

Comment: Got it,Thank You. Also, If you don't mind could you please also suggest some books to build an approach for questions like this ? I am currently using Kenneth A Ross and was unable to find examples like this. Thanks

Comment: I read a lot of math on my own in my teens in the 1960's and absorbed a lot from so many sources that I don't recall. But Dover Publications, formerly Dover Press, was then & still is a good source for cheap re-prints of old textbooks, including many great classics.